# Why Apple Reminder app on iPhone 7 / iOS 13.3.1 does not have hourly repeat option?

Tags: iphone, ios, reminders

I've been looking for ways to set up an hourly reminder. I've find a number of online article saying that starting with iOS 13, the native reminders app has an "hourly" option in the repeat menu.

Yet my native / Apple Reminders app doesn't have an Hourly repeat option. I have an iPhone 7 with iOS 13.3.1 installed. I have tried to delete / reinstall the app, still no "hourly" option.

What am I missing? Is there something I can do to change that?

Comment: Perhaps upgrade to iOS 13.4.1?

Comment: Just did, it doesn't change the list I have. I suspect my phone is "too old".

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem with an iPhone 11 Pro, so it's definitely not the age of the phone.  Could reliably follow the instructions from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/390157/380457) on an older Xs, but **Hourly** would just refuse to show up on the 11 Pro.

Then I noticed that the summary page on the 11 Pro (tap **< Lists** in upper-left from any list) had a link **Upgrade** right around the heading **My Lists** (sorry, didn't think of taking a snapshot), and tapping it asked for a confirmation (the upgrade is irreversible & breaks compatibility with other devices sharing the same lists using older software--see [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210220)), and then *voila!*, **Hourly** magically appears in the list of base periods on the **Repeat** screen.

Comment: This worked. Took me some time to understand the what *Upgrade* you were talking about. It is actually inside reminder app home screen.

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://9to5mac.com/2020/03/13/hourly-reminders-to-wash-hands-on-iphone-apple-watch/):

### How to set up hourly reminders on iPhone

1. Open the Reminders app on iPhone and create a new reminder
2. Tap the `i` to the right of your reminder
3. Tap the toggle next to `Remind me on a day`
4. Tap the toggle next to `Remind me at a time`
5. Choose Repeat and choose Hourly (or choose Custom)
6. Tap Done in the top right corner

[image]

**Pro tip:** Skip the manual set up and use a Siri command to set up hourly reminders. Something like “Remind me to wash hands every hour starting at 3 o’clock.”

Comment: As I say in my post, my native reminders app does not have the "hourly" option in the drop down menu...

Comment: You didn't mention the steps you were taking to see the 'hourly' option.  I also advised of a way to use Siri to set the reminder.  Did you try that option?

Comment: I follow exactly the steps you describe, but my list of options doesn't include "hourly". It starts at "daily", both in the standard list and in the custom list.